# The positive root of the transcendental equation $\ln x-\sqrt{x-1}+1=0$

Tags: special-functions, logarithms, mathematica, closed-form, transcendental-equations

I numerically solved the transcendental equation
$$\ln x-\sqrt{x-1}+1=0$$
and obtained an approximate value of its positive real root $$x \approx 14.498719188878466465738532142574796767250306535...$$

I wonder if it is possible to express the exact solution in terms of known  mathematical constants and elementary or special functions (I am especially interested in those implemented in [*Mathematica*](http://wolfram.com/mathematica))?

Comment: Try Lambert W function.

Comment: The Inverse Symbolic Calculator, to my surprise, did not recognize it.

Comment: Mathematica couldn't solve it with Solve[] and Reduce[].

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Have you been able to express it in terms of Lambert W?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Does "to my surpise" mean that you were able to find a rather simple form for the root?

Comment: Sadly, no. It only means that the few times I have used it, it has come p with something that fit.

Comment: @ Vladimir Reshetnikov, Nope! XD

Comment: From another paper, we use it to find a [complex solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28x%29-sqrt%28x-1%29%2B1%2Cx%3D%28-1-i%2B%281%2Bi%29%2Fsqrt%28pi%29Sum%5B%28e%5E%28-n%29+n%5E%28n-1%2F2%29+%28i*1%2F2%29%5En+BesselK%28-1%2F2+%2B+n%2C+i+n%29%29%2Fn%21%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C99%7D%5D%2B1%29%5E2%2B1)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to express this root in terms of special functions implemented in *Mathematica*.

---

Start with your equation
$$\ln x-\sqrt{x-1}+1=0,\tag1$$
then take exponents of both sides
$$x\ e^{1-\sqrt{x-1}}=1.\tag2$$
Change the variable
$$z=\sqrt{x-1}-1,\tag3$$
then plug this into $(2)$ and divide both sides by $2$
$$\left(\frac{z^2}2+z+1\right)e^{-z}=\frac12.\tag4$$
Now the left-hand side looks very familiar. Indeed, as it can be seen from [DLMF 8.4.8](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E8) or the formulae $(2),(3)$ on [this *MathWorld* page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html), it is a special case (for $a=3$) of the regularized gamma function
$$Q(a,z)=\frac{\Gamma(a,z)}{\Gamma(a)},\tag5$$
implemented in *Mathematica* as [`GammaRegularized[a, z]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GammaRegularized.html).

Its inverse with respect to $z$ is denoted as $Q^{-1}(a,s)$ and implemented in *Mathematica* as [`InverseGammaRegularized[a, s]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseGammaRegularized.html). We can use this function to express the positive real root of the equation $(4)$ is a closed form
$$z=Q^{-1}\left(3,\ \frac12\right).\tag6$$

Finally, using $(3)$ we can express the positive real root of your equation $(1)$ as follows:
$$x=\left(Q^{-1}\left(3,\ \frac12\right)+1\right)^2+1.\tag7$$

The corresponding *Mathematica* expression is

[`(InverseGammaRegularized[3, 1/2] + 1)^2 + 1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28InverseGammaRegularized%5B3%2C+1%2F2%5D+%2B+1%29%5E2+%2B+1)

We can numerically check that substitution of this expression into the left-hand side of the equation $(1)$ [indeed yields $0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5Bx%5D+-+Sqrt%5Bx-1%5D+%2B+1+where+x+%3D+%28InverseGammaRegularized%5B3%2C+1%2F2%5D+%2B+1%29%5E2+%2B+1).

I was not able to express the result in terms of simpler functions (like [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)).

Comment: A heuristic check confirming that the expression we found is indeed the root of the equation can be done in _Mathematica_ using [`PossibleZeroQ[With[{x = (InverseGammaRegularized[3, 1/2] + 1)^2 + 1}, Log[x] - Sqrt[x - 1] + 1]] (* True *)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html).