# Transcendental equations involving more than 2 terms

Tags: closed-form, transcendental-equations, lambert-w

I now how to solve transcendental equations involving only two terms like:

$xe^x=k$

$x=W(k)$

Where W(x) is the Lambert's Omega function.

But how can I solve (for $x$) a more general case? Like:

$xe^x-xe=k$

With $k$ being nonzero.

I mean an exact result, involving well-known functions and not simply an approximation.

Comment: Your problem seems very similiar to:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033398/lambert-w-function-with-rational-polynomial/1179641#1179641

And it involves a generalization of Lambert W.

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428057/the-positive-root-of-the-transcendental-equation-ln-x-sqrtx-11-0

a solution of a more general transcendental equation has been found in terms of InverseGammaRegularized[a, s].

Comment: Yes, I know about this result but how can I apply that in my case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burniston and Siewert built a solution for the equation:

$$ze^z=a(z+b)$$

through an integral representation.

== References ==

[68] C. E. Siewert and E. E. Burniston, "Solutions of the Equation $ze^z=a(z+b)$," Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 46 (1974) 329-337.

http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/pdfversions/68.pdf